# How does these two methods have different time complexity in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I am trying to solve the [Leetcode word search problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/word-search) .

I have two solutions which to me is identical although one of them returns in Time Limit Exceeded.

I read all resources around this and could not understand what is happening behind the scene.

Solution 1 with optimised time complexity:

```
class Solution(object):
    def bfs(self, position, visited, board, word):
        # print(position)
        if not word:
            return True

        destination = [(-1,0), (1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)]
        res = False
        for x,y in destination:
            new_postion_x, new_postion_y = position[0] + x, position[1] + y
            if (0<= new_postion_x < len(board)) and (0 <= new_postion_y < len(board[0])) and (new_postion_x, new_postion_y) not in visited:
                if board[new_postion_x][new_postion_y] == word[0]:
                    new_visited = visited.copy()
                    new_visited[(new_postion_x,new_postion_y)] = 1
                    res = res or self.bfs((new_postion_x, new_postion_y), new_visited, board, word[1:])
        return res

    def exist(self, board, word):
        for i in xrange(len(board)):
            for j in xrange(len(board[0])):
                if board[i][j] == word[0]:
                    t = self.bfs((i,j), {(i,j): 1}, board, word[1:])
                    if t:
                        return True
        return False
```

Solution two which returns TLE on execution for large input:

```
class Solution(object):
    def bfs(self, position, visited, board, word):
        print(position)
        if not word:
            return True

        destination = [(-1,0), (1,0), (0,1), (0,-1)]
        res = False
        for x,y in destination:
            new_postion_x, new_postion_y = position[0] + x, position[1] + y
            if (0<= new_postion_x < len(board)) and (0 <= new_postion_y < len(board[0])) and (new_postion_x, new_postion_y) not in visited:
                if board[new_postion_x][new_postion_y] == word[0]:
                    new_visited = visited.copy()
                    new_visited[(new_postion_x,new_postion_y)] = 1
                    t = self.bfs((new_postion_x, new_postion_y), new_visited, board, word[1:])
                    res = res or t
        return res

    def exist(self, board, word):
        for i in xrange(len(board)):
            for j in xrange(len(board[0])):
                if board[i][j] == word[0]:
                    t = self.bfs((i,j), {(i,j): 1}, board, word[1:])
                    if t:
                        return True
        return False
```

Comment: What have you derived as the time complexity for each algorithm?  What timing figures do you have?  Where in particular are you confused about the differences?

Answer (score 1):

The key line is here:

```
res = res or self.bfs((new_postion_x, new_postion_y), new_visited, board, word[1:])
```

Once `res` becomes `True`, this line will never execute `self.bfs()` again because the expression after the `or` does not need to be evaluated. This is called [short-circuiting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).
Thus, once a solution is found you don't make any more recursive calls and quickly return the `True` all the way back to the top.
An equivalent way of writing this, which might clarify it, would be:

```
if not res:
    res = self.bfs(...)
```

In the other solution:

```
t = self.bfs((new_postion_x, new_postion_y), new_visited, board, word[1:])
res = res or t
```

This will *always* call `self.bfs()` even when it's not needed anymore, with the net effect of always searching through the *entire graph* even if a solution has already been found.

Comment: `t = self.bfs()`
`res = res or t`

Will short-circuiting not happen over here once res is set to `True`

Comment: `t = self.bfs()` is already calling the recursion. Short-circuiting after that is pointless, the whole idea is to avoid calling `bfs()` if you don't need to.